# The output of this code is always coming 0

Tags: c++, series

The question is prime factorization using sieve of eratosthenes but regardless of parameters the output is always coming 0. Can you point out the error in the code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void prime( int n )
{
    int spf[100] = {0};

    for ( int i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        spf[i] == i;
    }

    for ( int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++ )
    {
        if ( spf[i] == i ) //unmarked
        {
            for ( int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i )
            {
                if ( spf[j] == j )
                {
                    spf[j] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    while ( n != 1 )
    {
        cout << spf[n] << " ";
        n = n / spf[n];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    prime( n );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `spf[i]==i;` is a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: If you turn your compiler warnings to a higher level, then the compiler will tell you about simple issues like this.

Comment: Good code formatting increases the readability of your code immensely. If you cannot be bothered to format the code as you write it, there are code beautifiers readily available. I used [`astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) `--style=ansi --indent-classes --indent-switches --indent-preprocessor --pad-oper --pad-paren-in --pad-header --unpad-paren --convert-tabs --break-blocks --add-brackets --align-pointer=middle`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```c
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        spf[i]==i;
     };
```

`==` is an equality comparison operator and not not an assignment.

Correct that to

```c
  spf[i]=i;
```